# npm install giving error for dependency module for express-validator

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I was trying to install the npm module `express-validator` . It is giving the following error for the one of the dependencies. Is any body aware how it can be fixed.

```
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'types/express' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'express-validator'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-59-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "express-validator"
npm ERR! cwd /home/abuzar/Desktop/node-basic/project
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.37
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

here is node version and npm version

Comment: Works for me? What version of node/npm are you using? http://d.pr/i/Rfhj

Comment: @brandonscript : updated the error log

Comment: Install a [much] more recent version of Node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it by upgrading both "nodejs" and "npm" to the latest version, you should install nodejs version 6.x by now (v6.10.1 for me) through [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

and to upgrade "npm" use the following command:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

npm (4.4.1) is the version I use now.

now you should be able to install packages like "express-validator" or others giving the same error.